# Building a well-rounded set of bits

Tags: drill, screwdriver, bits

First and foremost, please my ignorance as I'm new to the whole DIY thing. I bought a cheap set of drill bits, munched through them like butter, and so have now decided to make the investment into a proper selection. Happy to spend some more money on top-notch stuff.

My understanding is that to be well-rounded, I will want 3 sets:

1. Cobalt drill bits with a 135 degree tip for metal drilling
2. HSS tipped brad point drill bits with pilot point type things for wood
   drilling
3. Carbide tipped (or diamond?) bits for tiles, brick and
   concrete drilling.

Is this correct?

Does a titanium coating added to cobalt drill bits make a big difference; my understanding is it wears off quickly.

Secondary question is what to look for when buying impact-ready screwdriver bits. Common sense says I should look for cobalt drill bits to ensure they don't get munched up. Does a titanium coating make a difference here?

Availability of quality bits here in Bangkok is limited. I have found one company which sells Irwin bits. Are these considered quality bits? Or do they offer little more over brands like DeWalt?

Thanks,
Rob

--- PS comments

- For metal drilling, I feel TPP bits would be a great purchase.
  Thoughts?
- For wood drilling, I feel Irwin bits would be a great
  purchase. Thoughts?
- Still looking for the masonry bits.

Comment: The coating on Co-HSS bits you're talking about is Titanium Nitride, not metallic titanium, BTW.

Comment: When you buy metal drill bits, make sure to have the entire set professionally sharpened. Most bits are improperly sharpened from the factory, and cannot be used for precision work such as in a machine shop where thousandths of an inch count.

Answer (score 1):

For ordinary casual woodworking and household maintenance, almost any drill bit is sufficient. Fancy coatings make little difference for light-duty use. "Split points" can make drilling in exactly the right place easier on difficult materials; I haven't noticed much difference when drilling wood.

The kind of bit, in larger sizes, will make more difference -- above half an inch you start having to choose between spade bits (inexpensive), hole saws (mid priced, cleaner cuts), and Forstner-and-similar (more expensive, clean holes, can do some things neither of the others can,  but drill sliwer than hole saws; they're more often used on drill presses), or a few other less-common variations in the theme. (I own bits in all three of those categories, for different tasks).

I haven't used impact drivers enough to have opinions on those yet.

Comment: I believe you've completely mis-understood the question. He's talking about drill bits (for making holes in stuff), not screwdriver bits.

Comment: There are questions about both, but the svrewdrivet-bit question is about impact bits, true.

Comment: Better now, @someonesomewhere?

Comment: I interpreted the 'impact driver' part to be about drill bits that have hex shanks. As with regular drill bits, I aim for decent quality and keep in mind that drill bits are consumables.

Comment: I guess I could move the impact-ready screwdriver bits to a separate question. Will take views on this before I make the edit though; let me know what you guys think. Main question is about the drill bits in this thread. Appreciate your comments!

Comment: Thanks @keshlam. You suggest that getting inexpensive bits for 'around the house' work should be just fine. You don't think it will pay off in the long run to invest in a serious set? I know my father did make that investment and uses the same bits now as he did when I was a teenager, a long time ago. He is a casual DIY-er, I'm just starting out.

Comment: @RobdeJonge - If your dad has the same set from decades ago, he doesn't use them ;) That is, unless he has a set with like ten each, which I'd recommend buying : [(example)](http://www.screwfix.com/p/combination-drill-bit-kit-160-piece-set/88149). Anything below a half inch is disposable.

Comment: Unless you want to spend more money on a bit sharpener, or learn to sharpen bits by hand ... Neither if which is really worthwhile for most hobbyists; replacements are cheap enough.